# How to test a method that yields with arguments x times?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I created a class `SourceReader` that parses a file and would yield as many times depending on the number of recognized tokens inside the file.  For example if I parse `file1.txt`, it will yield with value `one` once only.  Another example is when I parse `file2.txt`, it will yield twice, first with the value `one`, and then with the value `two`.

How do I test this properly using rspec?  Here is what I have so far:

```
require './spec/spec_helper'

describe SourceReader do
  describe '#each_card' do

    context "given file with one card" do
      input_filename = './spec/data/file1_spec.txt'
      it 'yields once, with arguments "one"' do
        File.open(input_filename, 'r') do |file|
          sut = SourceReader.new(file)
          expect(sut.each_card).to yield_with_args('one')
        end
      end
    end

    context "given file with two cards" do
      input_filename = './spec/data/file2_spec.txt'
      it 'yields twice, with arguments "one", then "two"' do
        # some codes
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I am confused on how to implement the `expect { |b| object.action(&b) }.to yield_with_args` found in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = []
sut.each_card do |arg|
  arr << arg
end
expect(arr).to eq ['one', 'two']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [yield_successive_args](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:yield_successive_args):

```rb
# ... setting up test subject `sut` ...

expect { |b| sut.each_card(&b) }.to yield_successive_args('one', 'two')
```